# How to share interfaces across Angular Projects?

Tags: javascript, angular

So I'm creating a multi-site app in which every page is an angular project(made with ng g application, on the CLI). I also have a shared library that holds common components/services so they can be used by all the projects.

What I'd like to know is how to declare interfaces in my shared library and export them as well, so they can be accessed anywhere in the code where the common library is imported, just like any component.

I guess that a fast solution is to just import the interfaces from the library folder with the full path, but that would get ugly fast and is not maintainable since I'd have to manually update all of the imports in case something changes.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then all you have to do is export your interface in `public_api.ts` just like components or services. Anything that's exported in `public_api.ts` can be imported by other projects using `import { MyInterface, MyComponent, MyService } from "my-lib"`. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I think you're describing your real problem here: _is not maintainable since I'd have to manually update all of the imports in case something changes._  Do you want to get interfaces and so on **without** recompiling the code? is that what you're looking for? or are you just looking for a way to share interfaces between different projects?